# The question in suggested edits is displayed differently from the regular question view

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

This question [CollectionAssert.Contains(myList, myItem) != Assert.IsTrue(myList.Contains(myItem))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502988/collectionassert-containsmylist-myitem-assert-istruemylist-containsmyite) contains a link (to msdn) that is not 'clickable' i.e. its plain text only.

[image: showing the original question with a plain text link]

I edited the question and made it a link, to me although this is a simple change it makes the question much easier to read/use.

However when the edit went to peer review (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10222702) the rendered output shows the original having a 'clickable' link. Therefore it looks like my edit made literally no difference at all, just changed the markup, so it was rejected.
[image: showing the suggested edit page with rendering different from the question]

As I said, to me adding the link adds readability, but if mods disagree then fine, however I think in this case due to a rendering bug the mods didn't get the chance to actually view my edit and give it a fair peer-review.
This means my stats have an extra rejected edit, and worse the question stays unimproved.

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact the link (which works when copy-pasted) is inside parentheses.  I think the markdown renderer is trying to match to a `[Text](url)` form, but that post does not have the expected `[Text]` portion.   Why this renders correctly on the preview but not the post I have no idea.  In the meantime, I've edited the post to format the link.

Comment: I have had the same issue when editing an answer. The URLs weren't rendered as hyperlinks on the question page, but were in the edit review page.